# Dataset for TV commercials

Tags: data-request, usa, machine-learning, media, classification

I'm new to machine learning, and am trying to test machine learning on live TV video contents and detect the parts which are commercial ads. So I'm in need of some datasets for video contents and commercial ads for my trainingand classification purposes.

Where can I find such an ad dataset (real TV commercials)?

If you know any better ways to detect ads inside a given video, let me know. Or maybe you have a ready-to-use model, also would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found this in my own searches: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/tv+news+channel+commercial+detection+dataset

It's nearly 130,000 instances labeled TV or Commercial.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the commercials there comes a time when the screen is still and the company's name/symbol is all that there's on the screen.. you can train your program to search for and detect such times in the video. You can get lots of such pictures to train your program.
Then from that time the program can run backwards till it finds the point where ad started(i.e., lots of pixels changed).